# Vim `has('patch...')` returns true for unexisting patches

Tags: vim, patch

To check if my Vim version has patch 8.1.1310 I use:

```
echo has('patch-8.1.1310')
```

which returns `1` so Vim is patched with 8.1.1310. Out of curiosity I tried `echo has('patch-8.1.9999999999')`  which returns `1` even if no such patch exist (`:help changed-8.1`).

Question: Why `has()` returns 1 for unexisting patches?

My Vim version is 8.2.19.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in `:help has-patch`

> The "patch-7.4.248" feature means that the Vim version is 7.5 or
>       later, or it is version 7.4 and patch 248 was included.

If Vim version is 8.2, then `has('patch-8.x.y')` returns 1 for `x` equal to 0 or 1. And for any `y`.